# how to show indicator while http request in flutter

Tags: flutter

This is request function, but didn't show anything before list created and show item..what I want is to show indicator in this case, while loading items and before show it,Show indicator..

```
        Future<List<Film>> fetchFilms() async 
        {
                 var url = 'http://infinite-dawn-32185.herokuapp.com/api/all';
                 var response = await http.get(url);
    
                 var drugs = List<Film>();
                 if (response.statusCode == 200) 
                 {
                      var drugsJson = json.decode(response.body)['data'];
                      for (var drugJson in drugsJson) 
                      {
                           drugs.add(Drug.fromJson(drugJson));
                      }
                 }
                 return drugs;
         }
```

Comment: make a variable like `isLoading` and set it to false as default. Show the indicator conditionally when `isLoading` is true. Change `isLoading` to true, before you start the request ( before the line with `await http.get(...` and change it back to false after it is completed.

Comment: how to condition that with indicator widget @xDrago

Comment: You can do this easily like this: `... child: isLoading ?  CircularProgressIndicator() : SizedBox(),` . When you need to have `isLoading` in another widget, then you should use providers to access information across multiple widgets.

Comment: soory, I am new in flutter, where I put indicator condition in build() ?? @xDrago

Comment: depends on where you want to show the indicator. Really basic would be `build() { return isLoading ?  CircularProgressIndicator() : SizedBox();} ` I am using a ternary expression `condition ? "this happens on true" : "this happens on false"` to display the widget conditionally here.

Comment: No problem! Im happy that I was able to help you and I will add it as an answer, so you can accept it and help others with the same question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a variable and call it for example `isLoading`, set it to `false` as default.

Then show the indicator conditionally when isLoading is true. Change isLoading to true, before you start the request before the line with await http.get(... and change it back to false after it is completed.

```
bool isLoading = false;
...
 Future<List<Film>> fetchFilms() async 
        {
                 var url = 'http://example.com/api/test';
                 isLoading = true;
                 var response = await http.get(url);
                 isLoading = false;
    
                 var drugs = List<Film>();
                 if (response.statusCode == 200) 
                 {
                      var drugsJson = json.decode(response.body)['data'];
                      for (var drugJson in drugsJson) 
                      {
                           drugs.add(Drug.fromJson(drugJson));
                      }
                 }
                 return drugs;
         }
```

When you need to use `isLoading` in another widget or it is set in another one, you should use providers to access information across multiple widgets.

Here a short example how to use it:

```
...
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : SizedBox();
}
...
```

I am using a ternary expression `yourCondition ? "this happens on true" : "this happens on false"` to display the widget conditionally. If `isLoading` is true, it will show the ProgressIndicator and when it is false it will render a SizedBox with no size (so its basicly invisible)

Answer (score 2):

Use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinkit

This package provides an assortment of different loading icons.

Once you install the package to your project in your pubspec.yaml and use import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart' at the top of your file, place the following in your Build method for the file that you want the loading screen to appear, like so:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: SpinKitDoubleBounce(
      color: Colors.white,
      size: 100.0,
    )));
  }
```

The name used in the code snippet above "SpinKitDoubleBounce" determines which of the 23 loading icons you want to use. So if you want to use the DualRing icon for example, then use "SpinKitDualRing" instead.